# Getting an undefined value in jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a asp.net mvc view and I enter a value in a text field. I enter 'test'.

[image]

I'm trying to get the value from text field using jQuery.

```
var blogCommentValue = $('#comment_' + blogId).val();
```

[image]

However, the alert shows it as 'undefined'.

[image]

I ultimately want to test the text field value for being all whitespace before allowing it to pass into the controller. But because it is considered 'undefined', it make its way into the controller.

Why does jQuery/JavaScript see it as 'undefined'?

Yet I issue the same command again

```
var blogCommentValue = $('#comment_' + blogId).val();
```

before going to the controller.

It gets into the controller and it shows it as 'test'. The value I entered.

In the action method, I can see that the value 'test is there.

[image]

---

Here is the view html before the view code (not all of it).

```
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary Comment" data-id="@Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId" value="Comment">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span> Get Comment(s)
            </button>
        </div>

        @* Add comment area. *@
        <div id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}","commentsBlock", @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId)" style="border: 1px solid #f1eaea; background-color: #eaf2ff;">
            @*Centering the button with in-line CSS. *@
            <div class="AddCommentArea" style="margin-left: 30%;  margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 8px;">
                <input type="text" id="@string.Format("{0}_{1}", "comment", @Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId)" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment..." style="display: inline;" />
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addComment" data-id="@Model.BlogPublishedByBlogId.BlogId"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Here is the view code at the bottom (not all):

```
@section Scripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
         ...another function not shown.

        // For when clicking the 'addComment' button - 'Add a comment...'. Adding a new comment.
        $('.addComment').on('click', function () {
            var blogCommentValue = $('#comment_' + blogId).val();

            alert('Here 1. Value is: ' + blogCommentValue);

            // Uses a regular expression.
            if (/^\s*$/.test($('#comment_' + blogId).val())) {
                alert('Validation Error. The comment cannot be blank.')
            }
            else
            {
                var blogCommentId = 0;
                var userId = 0;
                var blogId = $(this).attr('data-id');
                // HERE I GET THE VALUE AGAIN! 
                var blogCommentContent = $('#comment_' + blogId).val();
                var likeCount = 0;
                var disLikeCount = 0;
                var dateTimeNow = new Date();
                var userName = "";
                var blogCommentProcessType = "I";

                // An object - the BlogComment model.
                  var blogComment = {
                    BlogCommentId: blogCommentId,
                    UserId: userId,
                    BlogId: blogId,
                    BlogCommentContent: blogCommentContent,
                    LikeCount: likeCount,
                    DisLikeCount: disLikeCount,
                    DateTimeOfBlogComment: dateTimeNow.toLocaleString(),
                    UserName: userName
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '@Url.Action("ProcessSaveBlogComment", "BlogPublished")',
                    data: { blogComment, blogCommentProcessType },
                    success: function (response) {
                       ... code not shown.
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert("Critical Error: something is wrong in the call to ProcessSaveBlogComment! Status: " + xhr.status + ". Error: " + thrownError.toString() + ". Response Text: " + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }               
        });

    });
</script>
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your model class you use in View in the controller and this userId field must be not empty.

After doing these:

```
var blogCommentValue = $('#comment_' + @Model.blogId).val();
```

need to work

Comment: I just realized that I needed to put this: var blogId = $(this).attr('data-id'); before var blogCommentValue = $('#comment_' + blogId).val();

Comment: If you want to capture value with a model, that's what I say, but that works too. @user3020047

Answer (score 0):

Your button has the an **id** [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). In order to get its value you need to refer to [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset):

```
var blogId = this.dataset.id;
```

If you prefer jQuery you can use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
var blogId = $(this).data('id')
```

```js
$('.addComment').on('click', function (e) {
    var blogId = this.dataset.id;
    var blogCommentValue = $('#comment_' + blogId).val();

    console.log('Here 1. Value is: ' + blogCommentValue);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary Comment" data-id="4" value="Comment">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment" aria-hidden="true"></span> Get Comment(s)
    </button>
</div>
<div id="commetsBlock_4" style="border: 1px solid #f1eaea; background-color: #eaf2ff;">
    <div class="AddCommentArea" style="margin-left: 30%; margin-bottom: 5px; margin-top: 8px;">
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="xxxxxx">
        <input type="text" id="comment_4" class="form-control" placeholder="Add a comment...." style="display: inline;" value="test">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary addComment" data-id="4">Click Me</button>
    </div>
</div>
```